# Sum rows based on other column values

Tags: r, sum, row, conditional-statements

I am a new R user and am looking for someone to point me in the right direction regarding what function I should use to achieve the following.

I have the following data frame. Output using the dput command.

```
structure(list(ID = 4701:4702, Date.1 = structure(c(5L, 5L), .Label = c("01/02/2013", 
"01/03/2013", "01/05/2013", "02/05/2013", "04/02/2013", "04/03/2013", 
"05/02/2013", "05/03/2013", "06/02/2013", "06/03/2013", "07/02/2013", 
"07/03/2013", "08/02/2013", "08/07/2013", "12/12/2012", "13/12/2012", 
"14/01/2013", "14/12/2012", "15/01/2013", "16/01/2013", "17/01/2013", 
"17/12/2012", "18/01/2013", "18/04/2013", "18/12/2012", "19/04/2013", 
"23/01/2013", "24/01/2013", "25/01/2013", "26/04/2013", "28/01/2013", 
"29/01/2013", "29/04/2013", "30/04/2013", "31/01/2013"), class = "factor"), 
 Day.of.Week.1 = structure(c(2L, 2L), .Label = c("Friday", 
"Monday", "Thursday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday"), class = "factor"), 
Sedentary.1 = c(511.5, 405.5), Light.1 = c(133.666666666667, 
119.166666666667), Moderate.1 = c(12.1666666666667, 13.1666666666667
), Vigorous.1 = c(4.33333333333333, 3.5), Axis.1.Counts.1 = c(157124L, 
126177L), Axis.1.CPM.1 = c(237.5, 233.1), Time.1 = c(661.67, 
541.33), Day.of.Week.2 = structure(c(1L, 4L), .Label = c("Friday", 
"Monday", "Thursday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday"), class = "factor"), 
Sedentary.2 = c(370.166666666667, 601.833333333333), Light.2 = c(113, 
162.5), Moderate.2 = c(12, 13), Vigorous.2 = c(4, 10), Axis.1.Counts.2 = c(141593L, 
201373L), Axis.1.CPM.2 = c(283.7, 255.8), Number.of.Epochs.2 = c(2995L, 
4724L), Time.2 = c(499.17, 787.33), Day.of.Week.3 = structure(c(NA, 
5L), .Label = c("Friday", "Monday", "Thursday", "Tuesday", 
"Wednesday"), class = "factor"), Sedentary.3 = c(NA, 463), 
Light.3 = c(NA, 121.666666666667), Moderate.3 = c(NA, 14.5
), Vigorous.3 = c(NA, 11.5), Axis.1.Counts.3 = c(NA, 196192L
), Axis.1.CPM.3 = c(NA, 321.3), Number.of.Epochs.3 = c(NA, 
3664L), Time.3 = c(NA, 610.67), Day.of.Week.4 = structure(c(NA, 
3L), .Label = c("Friday", "Monday", "Thursday", "Tuesday", 
"Wednesday"), class = "factor"), Sedentary.4 = c(NA, 472.333333333333
), Light.4 = c(NA, 149.166666666667), Moderate.4 = c(NA, 
11.3333333333333), Vigorous.4 = c(NA, 14.1666666666667), 
Axis.1.Counts.4 = c(NA, 218895L), Axis.1.CPM.4 = c(NA, 338.3
), Number.of.Epochs.4 = c(NA, 3882L), Time.4 = c(NA, 647), 
Day.of.Week.5 = structure(c(NA, 1L), .Label = c("Friday", 
"Monday", "Thursday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday"), class = "factor"), 
Sedentary.5 = c(NA, 383.166666666667), Light.5 = c(NA, 106.5
), Moderate.5 = c(NA, 8), Vigorous.5 = c(NA, 0.5), Axis.1.Counts.5 = c(NA, 
92163L), Axis.1.CPM.5 = c(NA, 185), Number.of.Epochs.5 = c(NA, 
2989L), Time.5 = c(NA, 498.17)), .Names = c("ID", "Date.1", 
"Day.of.Week.1", "Sedentary.1", "Light.1", "Moderate.1", "Vigorous.1", 
"Axis.1.Counts.1", "Axis.1.CPM.1", "Time.1", "Day.of.Week.2", 
"Sedentary.2", "Light.2", "Moderate.2", "Vigorous.2", "Axis.1.Counts.2", 
"Axis.1.CPM.2", "Number.of.Epochs.2", "Time.2", "Day.of.Week.3", 
"Sedentary.3", "Light.3", "Moderate.3", "Vigorous.3", "Axis.1.Counts.3", 
"Axis.1.CPM.3", "Number.of.Epochs.3", "Time.3", "Day.of.Week.4",  
"Sedentary.4", "Light.4", "Moderate.4", "Vigorous.4", "Axis.1.Counts.4", 
"Axis.1.CPM.4", "Number.of.Epochs.4", "Time.4", "Day.of.Week.5", 
"Sedentary.5", "Light.5", "Moderate.5", "Vigorous.5", "Axis.1.Counts.5", 
"Axis.1.CPM.5", "Number.of.Epochs.5", "Time.5"), reshapeWide = structure(list(
v.names = NULL, timevar = "ID2", idvar = "ID", times = 1:5, 
varying = structure(c("Filename.1", "Epoch.1", "Weight..kg..1", 
"Age.1", "Gender.1", "Date.1", "Day.of.Week.1", "Day.of.Week.Num.1", 
"Sedentary.1", "Light.1", "Moderate.1", "Vigorous.1", "Axis.1.Counts.1", 
"Axis.1.Average.Counts.1", "Axis.1.CPM.1", "Number.of.Epochs.1", 
"Time.1", "Calendar.Days.1", "Filename.2", "Epoch.2", "Weight..kg..2", 
"Age.2", "Gender.2", "Date.2", "Day.of.Week.2", "Day.of.Week.Num.2", 
"Sedentary.2", "Light.2", "Moderate.2", "Vigorous.2", "Axis.1.Counts.2", 
"Axis.1.Average.Counts.2", "Axis.1.CPM.2", "Number.of.Epochs.2", 
"Time.2", "Calendar.Days.2", "Filename.3", "Epoch.3", "Weight..kg..3", 
"Age.3", "Gender.3", "Date.3", "Day.of.Week.3", "Day.of.Week.Num.3", 
"Sedentary.3", "Light.3", "Moderate.3", "Vigorous.3", "Axis.1.Counts.3", 
"Axis.1.Average.Counts.3", "Axis.1.CPM.3", "Number.of.Epochs.3", 
"Time.3", "Calendar.Days.3", "Filename.4", "Epoch.4", "Weight..kg..4", 
"Age.4", "Gender.4", "Date.4", "Day.of.Week.4", "Day.of.Week.Num.4", 
"Sedentary.4", "Light.4", "Moderate.4", "Vigorous.4", "Axis.1.Counts.4", 
"Axis.1.Average.Counts.4", "Axis.1.CPM.4", "Number.of.Epochs.4", 
"Time.4", "Calendar.Days.4", "Filename.5", "Epoch.5", "Weight..kg..5", 
"Age.5", "Gender.5", "Date.5", "Day.of.Week.5", "Day.of.Week.Num.5", 
"Sedentary.5", "Light.5", "Moderate.5", "Vigorous.5", "Axis.1.Counts.5", 
"Axis.1.Average.Counts.5", "Axis.1.CPM.5", "Number.of.Epochs.5", 
"Time.5", "Calendar.Days.5"), .Dim = c(18L, 5L))), .Names = c("v.names", 
"timevar", "idvar", "times", "varying")), row.names = c(1L, 3L
), class = "data.frame")
```

I would like to sum for each row ACROSS columns `sedentary.1, sedentary.2, sedentary.3, sedentary.4` and `sedentary.5`. But I want each column to be included in the calculation ONLY if another column meets a certain criteria.

That is include column:

> -sedentary.1 if value in time.1 >= 377
>   -sedentary.2 if value in time.2 >= 377
>   -sedentary.3 if value in time.3 >= 377
>   -sedentary.4 if value in time.4 >= 377
>   -sedentary.5 if value in time.5 >= 377

I could do this in excel with the SumIf function but I don't know where to start in R for this. If you could point me to a function I could read up on I would be most grateful.

Many thanks,

Ash

Comment: You want to sum for each row, correct?

Comment: Thats correct Roman.Thank you.

Comment: I'm trying something like:   df = rowSums(Accel2[, c(Sedentary.1[Time.1 >= 377],Sedentary.2[Time.2 >= 377], Sedentary.3[Time.3 >= 377],
                        Sedentary.4[Time.4 >= 377],Sedentary.5[Time.5 >= 377],
                        na.rm = TRUE)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's probably a more efficient and/or clean looking way, but here I find which Time columns are not NA, and meet your criteria, then take rowSums after multiplying the Sedentary columns by the answer. TRUE will be treated as 1, and FALSE as 0 - so the result is the sum of rows meeting the criteria, as unwanted Sedentary values are multiplied by 0 before summing.

x is the name of the data frame you provided.

```
rowSums(x[c("Sedentary.1","Sedentary.2","Sedentary.3","Sedentary.4","Sedentary.5")] * (!is.na(x[,c("Time.1","Time.2","Time.3","Time.4","Time.5")]) & x[,c("Time.1","Time.2","Time.3","Time.4","Time.5")] >= 377), na.rm=TRUE)
```

**Edit for question in comments:**

Something like this should work:

```
# make TRUE/FALSE table
TF = !is.na(x[,c("Time.1","Time.2","Time.3","Time.4","Time.5")]) & x[,c("Time.1","Time.2","Time.3","Time.4","Time.5")] >= 377

# take rowSums of Sedentary.x when TF rowSums are greater than or equal to 3
rowSums(x[rowSums(TF) >= 3,c("Sedentary.1","Sedentary.2","Sedentary.3","Sedentary.4","Sedentary.5")] * TF[rowSums(TF) >= 3,], na.rm=TRUE)
```

You could make it a one-liner if you wanted, but I've split it into stages, saving the TRUE/FALSE table as "TF" to improve readability.

Comment: This works perfectly Ping.I prefer code like this as I can easily learn how it does what I want and apply in other parts of my script. Very many thanks.

Comment: Just remembered you mentioned finding the mean in your comment on the other answer. You won't be able to substitute rowSums for rowMeans here, as you'll be including the 0s in the mean calculation. If you want to keep the same method, you could find rowSums and divide by the rowSums of the TRUE/FALSE table.

Comment: Thanks Ping. I've managed that by converting the true false table to numeric values and a data frame then doing row sums of this. I'm wondering if there is a way I could add an additional criteria to the code you provided above. That is to do rowSums only for those which return rowSums of the true false greater than 3 (of the possible 5) from the new true/false data frame - if you follow?

Comment: You don't actually need to convert to numeric, as it will happen automatically when you try to use TRUE and FALSE with arithmetic (although there's no harm in it). I've added a solution to what I think you mean above.

Answer (score 0):

Indexing on other columns will get you started.

```
sum(df$Sedentary.1[df$Time.1 >= 377])
```

The plyr package is a nice way to get the sums of multiple columns at once.

```
library(plyr)

df2 <- ddply(df, .(), summarise, Sedentary.1 = sum(Sedentary.1[Time.1 >= 377], na.rm = TRUE), 
             Sedentary.2 = sum(Sedentary.2[Time.2 >= 377], na.rm = TRUE))

   .id Sedentary.1 Sedentary.2
1 <NA>         917         972
```

Comment: What about the rest, 1:5?

Comment: Well this should get the user started. The rest should be easy to work out.

Comment: example data includes NAs, so this answer alone won't work with all of the other columns. e.g. column 5

Comment: Thanks user2633645, Roman and Ping. I have indexed on other columns as per your first piece of code before.

Looking back at my question I don't think It's clear what I'm trying to do. I'm trying to find the sum or mean of these columns across each row. Could I use Ifelse and rowSums for this?

Thank you very much for taking the time to reply so far.

I will edit my question accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

I went about it like this. First I find which Time* columns have values >= 377, and then multiply that with the data.frame which is a subset of only Sedentary* columns. R handles TRUE as 1 and FALSE as zero, so values where there is FALSE, are turned to 0. If there's NA, the value will remain NA.

This code assumes that Time and Sedentary are listed in the same order.

```
sub.time <- mydf[, names(mydf)[grepl("Time", names(mydf))], ]
sumif <- sub.time >= 377
sub.sed <- mydf[, names(mydf)[grepl("Sedentary", names(mydf))], ]
apply(sub.sed * sumif, MARGIN = 1, sum, na.rm = TRUE)

        1         3 
 881.6667 2325.8333
```